# Cordova/Phonegap ignores fullscreen preference in config.xml on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have defined

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
```

But deploying through Xcode it ignores this. Even if I set hide status bar on the build settings. All my other config.xml settings seem to work, but not this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fullscreen` does not work on iOS 7 and above. Instead you can use [Cordova HiddenStatusbarOverlay Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-hidden-statusbar-overlay/tree/aef5a90d2161dd9d363242523883757a51d0fad0) to hide the statusbar.

Another way to hide it is to use a [gap:config-file](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_config_file_element.md.html) element to overwrite the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` property:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">
    <false/>
</gap:config-file>
```

Comment: I just want to add to this that you can modify the plist file in your cordova project with the following records: `Status bar is initially hidden: YES`  `View controller-based status bar appearance NO`

Comment: this combination **works** for me, too, testing on emulator running **iOS 8.2**

Comment: Hiding the status bar gets your app rejected on iOS 11

Answer (score 3):

use following preference tag. that works fine for me.

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Comment: Don;t know about previous versions, but this thing does not work and it is not part of the recommended approaches: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html

Comment: @IdoRan Remember to add this plugin (for which this preference is for) https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/