# I can't hide status bar with cordova

Tags: cordova

I develop iOS app with Cordova and Framework7.

But i cant hide status bar. I tried many suggestions but I could not. [check here blue background status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRT0D.png)

How can i disable? I want fullscreen app

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546873/cordova-phonegap-ignores-fullscreen-preference-in-config-xml-on-ios

Comment: [The information in the following link on stack overflow worked for me. You will need to place the code into Xcode. It is native code, but not hard to implement. Good Luck. -Rachel  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap/19884333#19884333)]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795921/how-to-completely-hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-using-cordova

Comment: for better result please test in real device....

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your status bar using native xcode changes like below

In the project setting

*General*

- Tick `Hide Status Bar` to true at bottom

*info.plist*

- Add new row `View-controller based status bar` with value `no`

**Updated**

Add this line to your config file and rebuild your app

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but i ticked Hide Status Bar but it did not work.

http://tinypic.com/r/28tf8t2/9

Comment: Also you have to add new row to `info.plist` have you added it too ?

Comment: Thanks again. This time status bar stuff disappeared but blue background is still here. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=hvw1v8&s=9#.WBs7PXdh2SM

Comment: Answer updated if you haven't tried this then this will solve your problem

Comment: I added that line to my config.xml but still same :( This is my config.xml = http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ipcdp5&s=9#.WBs_qHdh2SM

Comment: Then the last problem will be your splash screens, if you have added wrong size splash screens into xcode then your app will not open in full screen.

Comment: Thanks for all help Kirankumar. I tried a new blank Cordova Project. I applied everything you said. Everything is perfect work. I will check my app :/

Comment: Accept answer as right if you got help from this. Thanks!